Getting Invalid value for type in block 'product_video'. Type must be defined in schema Error
I an getting the "Invalid value for type in block 'product_video'. Type must be defined in schema" error when I try to save my product.json file.  Below I will first provide the product.json code the below that I will have the product-video.liquid file.  Ihave been working with this for the last hour and I an at a total loss.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.
product.json code
    {
  "sections": {
    "main": {
      "type": "main-product",
      "blocks": {
        "product_meta": {
          "type": "product_meta",
          "settings": {
          }
        },
        "variant_selector": {
          "type": "variant_selector",
          "settings": {
          }
        },
        "buy_buttons": {
          "type": "buy_buttons",
          "settings": {
          }
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "description",
          "settings": {
          }
        },
        "product_video": {
          "type": "product_video",
          "settings": {}
        }
      },
      "block_order": [
        "product_meta",
        "variant_selector",
        "buy_buttons",
        "description",
        "product_video"
      ],
      "settings": {
      }
    },
    "product-recommendations": {
      "type": "product-recommendations",
      "settings": {
      }
    },
    "recently-viewed-products": {
      "type": "recently-viewed-products",
      "settings": {
      }
    }
  },
  "order": [
    "main",
    "product-recommendations",
    "recently-viewed-products"
  ]
}


    <!-- product_video.liquid -->
`enter code here`{% if product.metafields.custom.videos %}
  <div class="product-videos">
    <h3>Product Videos</h3>
    <div class="videos-container">
      {% assign videos = product.metafields.custom.videos | split: ',' %}
      {% for video in videos %}
        <div class="video-wrapper">
          <iframe width="560" height="315" 
                  src="{{ video | remove: 'https://youtu.be/' | prepend: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/' }}" 
                  frameborder="0" 
                  allowfullscreen>
          </iframe>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% schema %}
{
  "name": "Product Video",
  "settings": [],
  "presets": [
    {
      "name": "Default",
      "category": "Custom"
    }
  ]
}
{% endschema %}

